# Cannot load properties file in java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, properties

I try to load properties file as below,

```
public class A_Main {

private static FileReader reader = new FileReader("D:\\Selenium_Workspace\\SeleniumTEST\\lists.properties");

private static Properties properties = new Properties();
private static properties.load(reader);

public static String UserName = properties.getProperty("lists.user");
public static String Passwd = properties.getProperty("lists.password");
......
......
......
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Configuration_Report conf = new Configuration_Report();
    try {
        conf.conf_report(UserName, Passwd);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
......
......
......
```

However, in eclipse it marked an error under below code,

```
private static properties.load(reader);
```

I try to change everything to public static also, however it seem the properties file cannot be load as *reader* seem not recognize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shared by Elliott above, you need to call the load function either from the static block. If you call it from the static block then you will have to take care that you initialize username and password (and any other dependencies) as well in the static block. Or the other option would be to initialize them at the starting of the main function:

**Static Block:**

```
public class A_Main {

private static Properties properties = new Properties();

public static String UserName = null;
public static String Passwd = null;

static{
     try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("D:\\Selenium_Workspace\\SeleniumTEST\\lists.properties"))
     {
         properties.load(reader);
         UserName = properties.getProperty("lists.user");
         Passwd = properties.getProperty("lists.password");
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

}
......
......
......
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Configuration_Report conf = new Configuration_Report();
    try {
        conf.conf_report(UserName, Passwd);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
......
......
......
```

**Inside Main Function:**

```
public class A_Main {

private static Properties properties = new Properties();
public static String UserName = null;
public static String Passwd = null;

......
......
......
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("D:\\Selenium_Workspace\\SeleniumTEST\\lists.properties"))
   {
         properties.load(reader);
         UserName = properties.getProperty("lists.user");
         Passwd = properties.getProperty("lists.password");
         Configuration_Report conf = new Configuration_Report();
         conf.conf_report(UserName, Passwd);
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
......
......
......
```

Comment: Hi, your solution indeed helps me..but it seem if dont initialize the username & password in static block also can works.

Comment: @MrAZ Yes definitely, you can initialize username and password in static scope anytime after properties are loaded from the provided file.

Answer (score 1):

That is not valid syntax for invoking a function on a class member. You could use a `static` initialization block. And that `FileReader` constructor can also throw an `Exception`. You could move that initialization into the same block. Like,

```
private static FileReader reader;
private static Properties properties = new Properties();
static {
    try {
        reader = new FileReader("D:\\Selenium_Workspace\\SeleniumTEST\\lists.properties");
        properties.load(reader);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it indeed help to resolve the error mark for that section..however, I have a new error mark under "private static FileReader reader = new FileReader...." . Do I need to put this under static initialization block also?

Comment: @MrAZ Edited. Sorry. Yes; that's one solution.